# Dim Blah as New GeckoWebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, browser

I added the gecko web browser element to the toolbox in `VBExpress`. The component works just fine when I manually put it into the designer, but when using `Dim Browser` As `New GeckoWebBrowser`, it says that the class `GeckoWebBrowser` is undeclared. How do I fix this so that it actually works?

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's in your toolbox does not mean it's actually available in your application.

Make sure you've included the required components in the References of your project. See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, make sure you import the required assemblies in your code :

```
Imports Skybound.Gecko
```

Here's a little howto that's quite simple : http://bpforums.info/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=284